# Writing same code inside of __add__ and __radd__, better way of doing this?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I have the following code.

```
def __add__(self, to_add):
    sum = self.val + to_add


def __radd__(self, to_add):
    sum = self.val + to_add
```

The code for add and radd is exactly the same.
I do understand why radd is necessary, but I feel it's redundant to write the same code twice if add and radd logic are the same, especially if each code is super long.

I did think of writing another function, i.e.

```
def addition(self, to_add):
    sum = self.val + to_add
```

and call this addition() inside of add and radd.

Is there a better/optimal way of writing this kind of code?

Comment: Call  `__add__`  inside `__radd__`

Comment: Oh yeah I guess that's also a way to go. thx!

Comment: What about ```__radd__ = __add__``` inside the class definition?